# Excel 2010 VBA Chartdata Not Working Getting 438 Error

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I am trying to update a powerpoint chart with excel data using VBA without linking to the powerpoint chart (using Excel 2010).

I have been trying to use ChartData but keep getting an error `438 Object Doesn't Support Property or Method` (please see the test code below). It errors on: `Selection.Chart.ChartData.Activate`.

If anyone knows how to fix this or has VBA code to update a Powerpoint chart with excel data using excel VBA 2010 without linking please let me know.

```
 Sub test3()

 Set pptApp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
 Set pptPres = pptApp.activepresentation
 pptPres.Slides(1).Chart("Chart1").Select
 Selection.Chart.ChartData.Activate
 Selection.Chart.ChartData.Workbook. _
        Worksheets("Test Graph Data").Range("B33:I36").Copy
 Selection.Chart.Paste

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For linked data, try...

```
With pptPres.Slides(1).Shapes("Chart1").Chart.ChartData
    .Activate
    .Workbook.Worksheets("Test Graph Data").Range("B33:I36").Copy
    .Workbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
End With
```

For an embedded workbook, try...

```
 pptPres.Slides(1).Shapes("Chart1").Chart.ChartData.Workbook. _
        Worksheets("Test Graph Data").Range("B33:I36").Copy
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!  I tried your suggestion and am getting an error says Member can only be accessed for a chart object.  Any suggestions about how to handle this error?

Comment: I have edited my post to include code for linked data.

Comment: Still trying to get this to work.  I tried both of the codes and it is still giving me an error 438 Object Doesn't Support Property or Method.  Any other suggestions?  Thank you for your help with this!

Comment: I've tested it, and it seems to work fine on my version of Excel, which is Excel 365.

Comment: On which line do you get an error?

Comment: First line - chart.chartdata.  I am using Excel 2010.

Comment: If you add the line `debug.Print pptPres.Slides(1).Shapes("Chart1").type
` prior to the line causing the error, what does it return in the Immediate Window?

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me with this!  It gives the same error 438 Object Doesn't Support Property or Method now on the line added.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand how you're getting that error message on that line.  How are you adding your chart to the slide?

Comment: I don't either.  I am trying to help out someone else and they sent it to me.  Looks like the graphs are linked.  I may have to upgrade my Office software from 2010 to 2019 to get this to work.  Thank you again for your kind assistance with this!